# How to create a Rock Paper Scissors command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm very new to discord.py and I want to create a Rock, Paper, Scissors command. I got it working, but I want to do it using user input.

I tried using the `await bot.wait_for` code, but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm not getting any errors, but it just doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Here's my code:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import random

bot = Bot(".")

@bot.command(help="Play with .rps [your choice]")
async def rps(ctx):
    rpsGame = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    await ctx.send(f"Rock, paper, or scissors? Choose wisely...")

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content.lower() in rpsGame

    user_choice = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

    comp_choice = random.choice(rpsGame)
    if user_choice == 'rock':
        if comp_choice == 'rock':
            await ctx.send(f'Well, that was weird. We tied.\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}')
        elif comp_choice == 'paper':
            await ctx.send(f'Nice try, but I won that time!!\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}')
        elif comp_choice == 'scissors':
            await ctx.send(f"Aw, you beat me. It won't happen again!\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}")

    elif user_choice == 'paper':
        if comp_choice == 'rock':
            await ctx.send(f'The pen beats the sword? More like the paper beats the rock!!\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}')
        elif comp_choice == 'paper':
            await ctx.send(f'Oh, wacky. We just tied. I call a rematch!!\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}')
        elif comp_choice == 'scissors':
            await ctx.send(f"Aw man, you actually managed to beat me.\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}")

    elif user_choice == 'scissors':
        if comp_choice == 'rock':
            await ctx.send(f'HAHA!! I JUST CRUSHED YOU!! I rock!!\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}')
        elif comp_choice == 'paper':
            await ctx.send(f'Bruh. >: |\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}')
        elif comp_choice == 'scissors':
            await ctx.send(f"Oh well, we tied.\nYour choice: {user_choice}\nMy choice: {comp_choice}")
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
You need to insert some debugging instrumentation (start with simple print statements).

Comment: Okay, I added the correct imports to my code. I think that's what you were asking for, but if I should add anything else, let me know. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_choice` is the whole message object, it contains an attribute for `content` which stores the content of the message.

This should fix your problem:

```
user_choice = (await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)).content
```

**References:**

- [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message)
- [`discord.Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.content)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx, choice):
    choices=["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    if choice not in choices:
        await ctx.send("error: please put rock, paper or scissors")
    else:
        await ctx.send(random.choice(choices))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx, choice):
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    choices=["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    comp_choice = random.choice(choices)
    asyncio.sleep(10)
    await ctx.send(f'GGS!, you chose {choice} and i chose {comp_choice} ')
    if choice not in choices:
        await ctx.send("error: please put rock, paper or scissors")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not right, its:

```
choices = "Rock", " Paper", "Scissors"
@bot.command() 
asyncio.sleep(1)
async def rps(inter, 
    choose=SlashOption(description="any-description",choices=choices)):
bot_choice = random.choice(choices) 
await inter.send("any-message")
if choice not in choices:
  await inter.send("Error! Please add Rock Paper Scissors!")
```

Comment: See how do I write a good answer [answer].